# How to show the permissions in AEM Security?

Tags: aem, aem-6, user-administration

I have encountered some issues after deploying my website assignment to the AEM publisher server instance and I am unable to access the permissions tabs within AEM security.

I have tried to re-publish my AEM project to the publisher instance but I am unable to get it working. I am unsure if there are any settings that has to be additionally configured in the publisher server as I did not do so in my dev server and was able to access the permissions tab in my localhost:4502.

[AEM Security - Permissions tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScyWk.png)

[AEM Security - Error in web console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z1dn.png)

I am new to Stackoverflow and would greatly appreciate any help and sharing of applicable knowledge if you have encountered similar issues previously.

Comment: 1. do you have access to error.log, probably there is an error trace. 2 I see your aem is behing a proxy server, (nginx in server header), can you try directly accessing AEM.

Comment: @awd I can't access the error.log file. However, if I do not use weblink to access but instead use the ip address to access the aem permissions, I am able to see the permissions in the json format.

Comment: Are you clicking once or double clicking on the user id?

Comment: @sadistic I clicked once on the user id.

Comment: @Richard Please try double clicking on the user id.

Comment: @Sadistic I have tried double clicking, I am still unable to see anything being displayed in the permission tab.

Comment: @RichardRodjues based on the screenshots I'd say that you are trying this in your production environment. If I had to guess I'd say your Dispatcher is filtering access to JSON resources. In your first screen shot it appears as if AEM tries to load `.cqactions.json` which is answered by a 404. According to the Dispatcher documentation: "All other requests are sent back to the web server with a 404 error code". So check your Dispatchers `/filter` rules.

Comment: @Jens Thank you for your all help. I've managed to request for the change in adding new /filter rules and the permission tab are able to display.

Comment: @RichardRodjues Great. I added my comment as an answer. Please accept it so other people can see the "official" answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Dispatchers `/filter` rules. They are probably blocking access to the requested `.cqactions.json`.